# Microsoft Graph - Multi Tenant Daemon App. Can't access all users

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, multi-tenant

I have created a multi-tenant daemon app in Azure from which I assumed I could access GET /users/ and get all users in all the connected tenants. However when this request is sent all I get is a list of users from one tenant (the one where the app is created). I have all the API permissions needed and I have granted them access.

I assume I missunderstand how the Graph workflow is supposed to work but after hours of googling I'm none the wiser. As of right now I'm just trying to get this to work in Postman. Any advice would be truly appreciated.

Comment: This is not possible. Your application will know the tenant information only when you login. If user A from A tenant signed in, you can only get the users from A tenant. The token is is always tenant-specific

Comment: In this case there are no users but rather an application. And if I need to re authenticate for each tenant this is fine.

Comment: Please refer this similar [scenario](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/issues/68#issuecomment-640446805). Hope it may helps you

Comment: Hi did you have a chance to look into my answer? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You have a misunderstanding of multi-tenant app.

Multi-tenant application is for offering a Software as a Service (SaaS) application to many organizations. It doesn't mean that the original app can access the resources from other tenants who have consented. It can only allow those tenants to access their own resources.

When the admin from another tenant (different from the original tenant) do consent for this multi-tenant app, an enterprise app which has the Graph permissions will be added to that tenant. Only that enterprise app have access to the data of that tenant.

So in your case, you are using client credential flow (app only without user), with the consent of the admin from other tenants, you can use the enterprise app added to those tenants to access the users of them.

Firstly, I assume you create multi-tenant app in tenant A. Make sure your multi-tenant app has the Application Permission `User.Read.All`.

Then [do the admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#construct-the-url-for-granting-tenant-wide-admin-consent) for tenant B using the admin consent endpoint (access the following url in a browser):

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id of tenant B}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id of the multi-tenant app}
```

Sign in with the admin account from **tenant B** to do the admin consent. This will added an enterprise app to tenant B.

Now you can get the token like this:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id of tenant B}/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id={client id of the multi-tenant app}
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret={client secret}
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

The access token will be able to list the users of tenant B.